# Что хранит в себе объект?

Tags: c#

Вывод на консоль - `41`, это размер объекта `o` в байтах. Откуда 40 байт и на что они потратились?

```
object o = new object();
using (Stream s = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(s, o);
    Console.WriteLine(s.Length);
}
```

Comment: вероятно, это размер метаданных

Comment: @iiKuzmychov ага, только вот каких? Знаю про то, что объект знает в каком потоке он находится или что-то типа того... как минимум из-за того, что при lock в объект (который мы закидываем в сам lock) записывается id (или не id, но что-то похожее) текущего потока для того чтобы потом вернуться. кстати по этой же причине await внутри lock запрещено

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-nrbf/75b9fe09-be15-475f-85b8-ae7b7558cfe5?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: `сериализованный объект != объект в памяти` - вас что именно интересует, структура CLR объекта или как работает `BinaryFormatter`? (покоиться бы ему с миром)

Comment: @aepot структура CLR объекта

Comment: Тогда вы неверно вычислили вес объекта. Если мне память не изменяет, 12 байт `object` весит.

Comment: @aepot А как правильно?

Comment: Грубо говоря вес всех полей + 8 байт https://habr.com/ru/post/263935/

Answer (score 5):

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

object o = new object();
using (var s = new MemoryStream())
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(s, o);
    Console.WriteLine(s.Length);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(s.ToArray().Select(x => (char)x)));
}
```

Вывод:

```
System.Object♂
```

То есть там записан сперва тип данных, а потом значение этого типа.